# How can I iterate through different items in xml output and then print out different values for each item using bash/linux shell commands

Tags: xml, bash, soap

I have the following XML output (produced by using curl to create a SOAP call to a WSDL):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Header/>
  <env:Body>
    <ns1:getNodesResponse xmlns:ns1="http://node.sdk.nms.ov.hp.com/">
      <return>
        <item>
          <created>2013-04-22T12:48:06.676Z</created>
          <deviceCategory>com.hp.ov.nms.devices.switchrouter</deviceCategory>
          <deviceDescription>Cisco Nexus C7018 DataCenter Switch</deviceDescription>
          <deviceFamily>com.hp.ov.nms.devices.cisconexus7000seriesswitches</deviceFamily>
          <deviceModel>ciscoNexusC7018</deviceModel>
          <deviceVendor>com.hp.ov.nms.devices.cisco</deviceVendor>
          <discoveryState>DISCOVERY_COMPLETED</discoveryState>
          <systemContact>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</systemContact>
          <systemDescription>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</systemDescription>
          <systemLocation>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</systemLocation>
          <systemName>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</systemName>
          <systemObjectId>.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.12.3.1.3.777</systemObjectId>
          <uuid>c8652440-caf2-490b-8892-cb914a39d19e</uuid>
        </item>
        <item>
          <created>2013-04-22T12:49:36.750Z</created>
          <deviceCategory>com.hp.ov.nms.devices.switchrouter</deviceCategory>
          <deviceDescription>Cisco Nexus C7018 DataCenter Switch</deviceDescription>
          <deviceFamily>com.hp.ov.nms.devices.cisconexus7000seriesswitches</deviceFamily>
          <deviceModel>ciscoNexusC7018</deviceModel>
          <deviceVendor>com.hp.ov.nms.devices.cisco</deviceVendor>
          <discoveryState>DISCOVERY_COMPLETED</discoveryState>
          <systemContact>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</systemContact>
          <systemDescription>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</systemDescription>
          <systemLocation>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</systemLocation>
          <systemName>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</systemName>
          <systemObjectId>.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.12.3.1.3.777</systemObjectId>
          <uuid>6f5ef089-6a51-459f-bde1-9cf18e4f8ca7</uuid>
        </item>
        <item>
          <created>2013-04-22T12:51:56.872Z</created>
          <deviceCategory>com.hp.ov.nms.devices.switchrouter</deviceCategory>
          <deviceDescription>Cisco Nexus C7018 DataCenter Switch</deviceDescription>
          <deviceFamily>com.hp.ov.nms.devices.cisconexus7000seriesswitches</deviceFamily>
          <deviceModel>ciscoNexusC7018</deviceModel>
          <deviceVendor>com.hp.ov.nms.devices.cisco</deviceVendor>
          <discoveryState>DISCOVERY_COMPLETED</discoveryState>
          <systemContact>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</systemContact>
          <systemDescription>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</systemDescription>
          <systemLocation>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</systemLocation>
          <systemName>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</systemName>
          <systemObjectId>.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.12.3.1.3.777</systemObjectId>
          <uuid>bae02b8c-25d4-4b53-bef0-2d5b14536e0b</uuid>
        </item>
        </item>
      </return>
    </ns1:getNodesResponse>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

How could I go about iterating through each `<item>` and then for each item, print out different values for the item? I was thinking about just grepping for `<item>`s and then picking through the data between every `<item>` and `</item>`, but I was not sure if there was a better way to do this. I would be using bash/linux shell commands

Pseudo code:

```
for i in item
     print i.uuid,i.systemName
```

Comment: Unless I just missed it...what language are you using?

Comment: @Ageonix sorry about that, I would be using bash/linux shell commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use a xml parser or xml querying language instead of regex and bash commands. If you are programming in some language see `DOM`,`SAX`,`StAX` etc based xml parsers. You can also use SQL like syntax for xml by using `XQuery`; another language to get your data can be `xpath`.

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xquery_intro.asp

But if you still insist using bash tools.. here is a `sed` 1-liner:

```
$ sed -n -e '/<item>/,/<\/item>/p' xml | sed -r -e 's/^\s*<uuid>(.*)<\/uuid>/\1/g' -e 's/^\s*<systemName>(.*)<\/systemName>/\1/g' -e '/^\s*</d' | sed -n 'N;s/\n/,/g;p'
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,c8652440-caf2-490b-8892-cb914a39d19e
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,6f5ef089-6a51-459f-bde1-9cf18e4f8ca7
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,bae02b8c-25d4-4b53-bef0-2d5b14536e0b
$
```

Breakdown:

1. `sed -n -e '/<item>/,/<\/item>/p' xml`
2. `sed -r -e 's/^\s*<uuid>(.*)<\/uuid>/\1/g' -e`
   `'s/^\s*<systemName>(.*)<\/systemName>/\1/g' -e '/^\s*</d'`
3. `sed -n 'N;s/\n/,/g;p'`

Expression 1: suppress default printing, and `p`(print) lines with a range. start line should be match regex `<item>` and end line must match regex `</item>. This gives you all items`...`.

Expression 2: Now we strip off the tags `<uuid>`, `</uuid>`, `<SystemName>`, `</SystemName>` and just keep the inner portion using regex and `s`(substitute) command.

Expression 3: Suppressed default printing(`-n`); `N` reads next line from input and concatenates it to previous line(already read by sed into pattern space); therefore concatenating consecutive lines separated by a newline `\n`. Then we substitute the `\n` char with comman and print the pattern space(`p`).

Comment: thanks! I appreciate the xpath and xquery suggestions as well. I don't have root access to the machine that I am running this on, but I'm going to see if I can get those to compile with the current libraries that I have access to.